# Testing your Xamarin app on Android device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin-studio

I've develop a test application in Xamarin Studio (Android with C#) and wanted to test it on my phone.

The application worked just fine in the Device emulator (Same OS version) but when I install / open it on my phone, it just says "TestApplication stopped working" I know from the online search that thousands of issues could cause this error message but my questions is :

Is exporting my app on my droid as simple as :

- Compiling the app
- Taking the **signed** .apk in the .bin folder
- Dragging that .apk on the phone (I'm using AirDroid to drag the file)
- Running the .apk (installing the app)

Am I missing an obvious, magic step ?

Comment: I don't know how Xamarin Studio works, but this happened to me when trying the same, using `Visual Studio`. I found out the application worked only when building in `Release` mode. Not sure if Xamarin Studio has the same options (Debug / Release / etc)

Comment: @HighCore Glad to see I'm not the only one. Will try that right away.

Comment: @HighCore I would give you soo much rep for this.... 0_o please post as an answer because it solved my issue.

Comment: Yup, it only runs or deploys to device on `Release` mode. The main issue is that the options **disappear** from the menu instead of being disabled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know how Xamarin Studio works, but this happened to me when trying the same, using Visual Studio.

I found out the application worked only when building in `Release` mode.

Not sure if Xamarin Studio has the same options (Debug / Release / etc)

Comment: Another thing that I noticed while working through this is that you NEED to make sure that MTP is enabled on the phone. Without that, the phone won't allow the computer to deploy the app to it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I'm a bit late here, but it seems time changed things.

What I had to do (and I can't seem to understand why it's not more intuitive than that) is to:

1. Right click on Solution
2. Archive
3. Follow the Wizard steps

Better instructions can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows